# How to make secure signed apk which is difficult to reverse engineer?

Tags: android, gradle, apk

I am using `multidex enabled` in my project. When I use **minifyEnabled true** I got this error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.

  > Job failed, see logs for details

**Here is my gradle file :**

```
        apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 25
        buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.app.example"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 25
            versionCode 9
            versionName "1.8"
            multiDexEnabled true


        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled true
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
        dexOptions {
            preDexLibraries = false
        }
        productFlavors {
        }

        lintOptions {
            checkReleaseBuilds false
        }
    }


    repositories {

        maven {
            url 'https://dl.bintray.com/ayz4sci/maven/'
        }

    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'


    }
```

> **UPDATE**    (After seeing logs as suggested by **kevin**)

- I add this lines dontwarn

  ```
  -dontwarn com.squareup.picasso.**
  -dontwarn com.vungle.**
  -dontwarn twitter4j.**
  ```

<s>and its work but I'm using d-max/spots-dialog and its not showing after signed apk</s>

It's also solved using -keep class .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use minify, by default you enable code obfuscation..

It also removes unused methods. I had 20k+ methods from Google Support Library, when I use minify, it got cut down to about.. 5k or so.. So you have to modify your `proguard-rules` for your app to tell the code obfuscator to not remove your classes.

For example :

```
-keep class com.app.example.** {*;}
-dontwarn com.app.example.**

# Ensure annotations are kept for runtime use.
-keepattributes *Annotation*
# Don't remove any GreenRobot classes
-keepnames class org.greenrobot.** {*;}
# Don't remove any methods that have the @Subscribe annotation
-keepclassmembers class ** {
    @de.greenrobot.event.Subscribe <methods>;
}
```

You can find which class is needed by reading the error log, it usually say something in the line of "need class x but not found"

Comment: **I found only this :** Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\workspace\Appname\app\build\intermediates\proguard-rules\release\aapt_rules.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)

Comment: @bdevloper Hmm try using only `proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')` at your gradle, And also, it says that the file for proguard isn't found, so check whether the directory is there

Comment: Means if i'm not use minifyEnabled in gradle reverse engineering of my apk is difficult ?

Comment: and directory is there but aapt_rules.t‌​xt is not found

Comment: If you don't enable it, it will be easier to reverse engineer. I've tried and I can reverse engineer my app easily. With `minify enabled`, the class names would get.. Obfuscated, for example from `MainActivity.class` to `asdfg.class`.
Ah I see.. I've never encountered this, I also don't have aapt_rules.txt and I don't even have that directory. Maybe try copying and renaming your proguard into aapt_rules

Comment: I decompiled my  app and i can see my app class easily after remove  minify enabled. how can stop it.

Comment: By enabling minify. That aapt_rules.txt shouldn't be a problem though, it is automatically generated, the problem lies somewhere else

Comment: You are on the right path by using `minifyEnabled true`. But the problem is with the configuration, any other thing in log other than that unable to find path?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137632/discussion-between-b-devloper-and-kevin-murvie).

Comment: Guys please join us in chatroom

Comment: Ah sorry I was away on a meeting, try adding `-keep class ...` for each of your already `-dontwarn`, you need to notify it to keep its class too

Comment: I think it's resource problem i only not showing that dots...Loading dialog were prompt

Comment: @bdevloper How did you solve it? I need to leave office yesterday hahaha.. If you need help, just post a new question, if I come accross it, I can help :D

Comment: I posted log in chat did u see that? I just use **-keep and -dontwarn** and it solved all issu

Comment: but I have new problem now

Comment: How to hide "user_id" like strings which i posted to server using volley.means how to hide string value

Comment: I am using **AES Algorithms.** for hide my url but it is also in " "  so i send my key to server it can also be hacked . so how hide that also?

Comment: @bdevloper No, in my screen no chat about you using -keep, but I told you about that here in comment. Hm.. I guess you  should use an encryption to send the user_id. You should post this as a new question btw